# Solve $\int_{-1}^1 z^i dz$, where the integrand denotes the principle branch $z^i = \exp(i \log z)$, $(|z|>0, -\pi < Arg z < \pi)$ .

Tags: complex-analysis

> Solve $\int_{-1}^1 z^i dz$, where the integrand denotes the principle branch $z^i = \exp(i \log z)$, $(|z|>0, -\pi < Arg z < \pi)$. The path of integration is any contour from $z=-1$ to $z=1$ that except for its endpoints, lies above the real axis.

So this is how the solution for this question is described.

$$z^i = \exp (i\log z)$$
*An antiderivative for this branch cannot be used since the branch is not even defined at at $z=-1$. But the integrand can be replaced by the branch $z^i = \exp(i \log z)$, where $|z|>0, \frac{-\pi}{2} < arg z < \frac {3\pi}{2}$ since it agrees with the integrand along C. Using an antiderivative to the new branch we can now write*

$$[\frac{z^{i+1}}{i+1}]^1_{-1}$$
$$= \frac{1 + e^{-\pi}}{2} (1-i)$$

Now whatever was written in italics made no sense to me. I dont understand why the principle branch is not defined at $z=-1$ since it can be written as $\exp(0  -\pi i)$ without any problems. I also dont get why and what changes to the principle branch, and what was even the point of the whole exercise if they are just going to integrate it directly. Can anyone please explain the theory behind this?

Comment: The principal branch is only defined for complex numbers $z\neq 0$ such that $-\pi <\text{Arg}(z) <\pi $. Note the strict inequality; does $z=-1=\exp(-i\pi)$ satisfy this? So, it is not defined on the non-positive real axis $(-\infty, 0] $.

Comment: the principal argument function is defined for $\arg(z)\in(-\pi,\pi]$ so yes, in the negative axis, except at zero, you have that $\log z=\log|z|+i\pi$. However the principal logarithm is holomorphic just in $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty ,0]$ besides the fact that it is defined in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, so an antiderivative can be defined just in $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty ,0]$. I dont understand the exercise either, I mean, what it tries to "show"